# How do i completely uninstall ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana)?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I search on internet that we have to unistall each of the ELK part one by one like unistall stand-alone kibana, elastic search, and logstash. Is there any command which no need to unistall all of them one by one but using only one single command ?

this is the package that i used in my source.list

```
deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main
```

Comment: how were the sources codes (or packages?) installed?

Comment: @thrig `deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main`

Comment: @thrig i used this package, and i just install like common package, such `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install elasticsearch, kibana, logstash` etc

Comment: does `apt-get` have an "uninstall" command that may be mentioned in its man page?

Comment: @thrig so the command will be `apt-get unnistal ...` ?

Comment: ... Probably read the documentation instead of asking : `$ man apt-get` ... or read on-line http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt.8.html

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As per ELK V.7 upwards, an IDS security apps for server called [WAZUH](https://wazuh.com/) have [some documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/3.9/installation-guide/installing-elastic-stack/elastic_server_deb.html#uninstall) about uninstalling ELK from Debian systems. It says:

> To uninstall Elasticsearch: `apt-get remove elasticsearch`
>
> There are files marked as configuration and data files. Due to this designation, the package manager doesn’t remove those files from the filesystem. The complete files removal action is a user responsibility. It can be done by removing the folder /var/lib/elasticsearch and /etc/elasticsearch.

and

> To uninstall Kibana: `apt-get remove kibana`
>
> As in the previous case, the complete files removal can be done by removing the folder /var/lib/kibana and /etc/kibana.

Comment: Just curious about the silent downvotes, is it mainly the fact that it is missing Logstash?

Comment: @Fontanka16 yeah, i wonder why i got downvoted

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the configured data directories in the respective files under /etc/elasticsearch, logstash and kibana. Remember the data directories. /var/lib/elasticsearch and so on are the defaults.

Then:

```
apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch logstash kibana
```

This should remove the package contents and the config files. As for data and cache files, you need to check the directories configured in the config files and remove those with manually.